# border around get_tk_widget() frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have two canvas widgets of matplotlib plots embedded in tkinter. I would like to draw a border around these frames using `fig1_canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=3)` and
`fig2_canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=3)`

However this only works for one of the two.

[image]

How can I resolve?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)

ax1.plot(t, np.cos(t))
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
fig1_canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=3)

ax2.plot(t, np.sin(t))
fig2.tight_layout()
fig2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
fig2_canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=3)

frame1 = tk.Frame()
frame2 = tk.Frame()

tk.Label(frame1, text='hello').pack()
tk.Label(frame2, text='world').pack()

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
fig1_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1)
fig2_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is only ever one element highlighted at once. If you press the TAB key you it will highlight the other.

Comment: ah ok (I guess that is also in the name), so how can I put a border around them then instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a flat border with a different color around your figures, you can just embed them in a frame of the desired color, letting a margin with the `padx` and `pady` options:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()
# frames to create the black border:
fig_frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background='black', padx=2, pady=2)  
fig_frame2 = tk.Frame(root, background='black', padx=2, pady=2)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)

ax1.plot(t, np.cos(t))
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=fig_frame1)  # set master of fig1_canvas to the border frame
fig1_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(padx=1, pady=1)  # change padx and pady to choose the thickness of the border

ax2.plot(t, np.sin(t))
fig2.tight_layout()
fig2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=fig_frame2)
fig2_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(padx=1, pady=1)

frame1 = tk.Frame()
frame2 = tk.Frame()

tk.Label(frame1, text='hello').pack()
tk.Label(frame2, text='world').pack()

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
# put the border frames in the root window
fig_frame1.grid(row=0, column=1)
fig_frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

[image]